# I have something wrong in all my projects after install Xcode 4.2 IOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

After installing Xcode 4.2 all my projects code lines that have spaces changed to stange character

Have a look at this screen shot:[image: every space is replaced by this strange character]

Comment: i Fix it just if one have this problem go to Editor-> Hide Invisibles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Choose the 'Hide Invisibles' command from the Editor menu.**

There's nothing wrong with your projects; you just have Xcode configured to show you the "invisible" (i.e. white space) characters.

Comment: Thanks i have solve it before you answer in the comment on my post..but i will mark your answer :-(